# How to create a Google Cloud Storage Signed URL using Elixir or Erlang?

Tags: erlang, rsa, google-cloud-storage, elixir, pkcs#1

I'm currently trying to get my elixir web server to generate signed urls for Google Cloud Storage so that I can generate file urls that expire.
Unfortunately when I try to use the generated urls I get the following error:

```
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
</Message>
```

I am able to generate signed urls that work via the gsutil tool, although it is quite slow, and also via the python example given here:

[Google Cloud Storage Signed URLs Example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python)

My current implementation in Elixir is based on the above Python example and looks like this:

```
@default_expiration 1000
  def construct_string(http_verb, content_md5, content_type, expiration_timestamp, canonicalized_extension_headers, canonicalized_resource) do
    "#{http_verb}\n
    #{content_md5}\n
    #{content_type}\n
    #{expiration_timestamp}\n
    #{canonicalized_extension_headers}
    #{canonicalized_resource}"
  end

  def load_secret_pem do
    load_local_key_file("/path/to/key")
  end

  def load_local_key_file(path) do
    {ok, pem_bin} = File.read(path)
    [rsa_entry] = :public_key.pem_decode(pem_bin)
    key = :public_key.pem_entry_decode(rsa_entry)
  end

  def base64Sign(plaintext) do
    key = load_secret_pem()
    signature_bytes = :public_key.sign(plaintext, :sha256, key )
    Base.url_encode64(signature_bytes)
    |> String.replace("-", "%2B")
    |> String.replace("_", "%2F")
    |> URI.encode_www_form
  end

  def make_url(verb, path, content_md5 \\ "", content_type \\ "") do
    client_id = GCloud.Credentials.client_email() |> URI.encode_www_form
    expiration =  :os.system_time(:seconds) + @default_expiration
    base_url = GCloud.Storage.base_uri() <> path
    signature_string = construct_string(verb, content_md5, content_type, expiration, "", path )
    url_encoded_signature = base64Sign(signature_string)
    IO.puts "#{base_url}?GoogleAccessId=#{client_id}&Expires=#{expiration}&Signature=#{url_encoded_signature}"
  end
```

How are signed urls correctly signed using Elixir or Erlang?

Comment: In case some runs into issue when implementing v4 signing: https://github.com/toraritte/guss/blob/add_v4_signing/lib/guss/v4/storage_signer.ex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string construction in `construct_string` may be doing things you do not realize. Remember that Python syntax is not the same, and has other opinions on spaces.

```
defmodule Test do
  def foo(a,b) do
    "#{a}\n
    #{b}"
  end
end
IO.inspect Test.foo(1,2)
# output:
"1\n\n    2"
```

If you use a heredoc with `"""` instead, the leading spaces go away, but your newlines are still duplicated. This approach is probably a bad idea, though, because if you save the file from a windows machine, you may have `\r\n` as the line ending in the editor, and getting rid of those is an unnecessary annoyance anyway.

Instead, I think you should change your approach here to be something like this:

```
def construct_string(http_verb, content_md5, content_type, expiration_timestamp, canonicalized_extension_headers, canonicalized_resource) do
  headers = Enum.join([http_verb, content_md5, content_type, expiration_timestamp], "\n")
  "#{headers}\n#{canonicalized_extension_headers}#{canonicalized_resource}"
end
```

I'm not sure if there are any other errors, but this stands out to me immediately.

Comment: I have added your suggestions and my requests are now properly formatted, thanks for identifying that. Sadly I still get the same "Signature does not match" error from Google cloud storage, I wonder if the erlang public_key:sign function supports what I am trying to do, or perhaps I am using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this working, I did this by opening a python and elixir REPL side by side, executed each step in both with a test string and compared the output for discrepancies, there where no discrepancies after hashing or signing the test string, but there was after base64 encoding, so I changed:

```
def base64Sign(plaintext) do
    key = load_secret_pem()
    signature_bytes = :public_key.sign(plaintext, :sha256, key )
    Base.url_encode64(signature_bytes)
    |> String.replace("-", "%2B")
    |> String.replace("_", "%2F")
    |> URI.encode_www_form
end
```

to

```
def base64Sign(plaintext) do
    key = GCloud.Credentials.load_secret_pem()
    signature_bytes = :public_key.sign(plaintext, :sha256, key )
    Base.encode64(signature_bytes)
    |> URI.encode_www_form
end
```

This combined with [asonge's string construction advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388477/how-to-create-a-google-cloud-storage-signed-url-using-elixir-or-erlang/35390190#35390190) solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

using [gcs_signer](https://hex.pm/packages/gcs_signer) from hex.pm:

```
Application.get_env(:goth, :json)
|> Poison.decode!
|> GcsSigner.Client.from_keyfile()
|> GcsSigner.sign_url(bucket, object)
```

In Google Cloud Platform environments, such as Cloud Functions and App
  Engine, you usually don't provide a `keyFilename` or `credentials` during
  instantiation, 
 
then you can use [signBlob api](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob) see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59394149/how-to-generate-signed-url-for-google-cloud-storage-objects-using-service-accoun/59443900#59443900)