# How to generate Signed URL for google cloud storage objects using service-accounts-for-instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, elixir, google-cloud-storage

I am  using [signed-urls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) to give my clients temporary access to google cloud storage objects 
I have a service account json which looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "my-project",
  "private_key_id": "abcdef1234567890",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<key...>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "my-app@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "1234567890",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/my-app%my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

and here is how I create the signed url -code written in elixir (code from [gcs_signer](https://github.com/shakrmedia/gcs-signer-elixir/blob/master/lib/gcs_signer.ex#L33) lib)

```
 def sign_url(private_key, client_email, bucket, object) do
    verb = "GET"
    md5_digest = ""
    content_type = ""
    expires = DateTime.utc_now() |> DateTime.to_unix() |> Kernel.+(1 * 3600)
    resource = "/#{bucket}/#{object}"

    signature = [verb, md5_digest, content_type, expires, resource]
                |> Enum.join("\n") |> generate_signature(private_key)

    url = "https://storage.googleapis.com#{resource}"
    qs = %{
           "GoogleAccessId" => client_email,
           "Expires" => expires,
           "Signature" => signature
         } |> URI.encode_query

    Enum.join([url, "?", qs])
  end

  defp generate_signature(string, private_key) do
    private_key = process_key(private_key)

    string
    |> :public_key.sign(:sha256, private_key)
    |> Base.encode64
  end

  defp process_key(private_key) do
    private_key
    |> :public_key.pem_decode
    |> (fn [x] -> x end).()
    |> :public_key.pem_entry_decode
    |> normalize_private_key
  end

  defp normalize_private_key(private_key) do
    # grab privateKey from the record tuple
    private_key
    |> elem(3)
    |> (fn pk -> :public_key.der_decode(:RSAPrivateKey, pk) end).()
  end
```

in this was I create a signed url using the `private_key` from the json file

for security reasons we moved to [service-accounts-for-instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#using) instead of using json credentials 
 
my question is how to create a signed url when using `service-accounts-for-instances` when I don't have a json credential? 
the only thing I have is the `servie_account_email` which look like this: `my-app-gsa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`  
Should I use the [signBlob](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob) api? if so how would my curl requests look like?

Comment: When you use (reference) Google Cloud credentials (service account) on Google Compute Engine (any compute service), you do not have access to the Private Key. This means that you must either use Google Cloud libraries or write your own code to use SignBlob (which means that Google is accessing the private key for you). This link provides information on the REST API which you can then map to curl parameters: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob

Comment: To see how the CLI generates API calls add the command line option `--log-http`.  You can then trace an entire presigned URL generated by `gcloud`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my code in elixir returns an encrypted link in the following format:
`https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/my-file?Expires=1576437298&GoogleAccessId=my-gsa%40project.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Signature=FUgBzvfFCa0YAL` 
following google api for [signBlob](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob)

```
@base_url @https://storage.googleapis.com

def generate_encrypted_url() do
    gcp_service_account = "my-gsa@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    bucket = "my-bucket", 
    object ="my-file"
    get_signed_url(gcp_service_account, bucket, object)
end



  def get_signed_url(gcp_service_account, bucket, object) do
    %Tesla.Client{pre: [{Tesla.Middleware.Headers, :call, [auth_headers]}]} = get_connection()
    headers = [{"Content-Type", "application/json"}] ++ auth_headers
    url = "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/#{gcp_service_account}:signBlob"
    expires = DateTime.utc_now() |> DateTime.to_unix() |> Kernel.+(1 * 3600)
    resource = "/#{bucket}/#{object}"
    signature = ["GET", "", "", expires, resource] |> Enum.join("\n") |> Base.encode64()
    body = %{"payload" => signature} |> Poison.encode!()
    {:ok, %{status_code: 200, body: result}} = HTTPoison.post(url, body, headers)

    %{"signedBlob" => signed_blob} = Poison.decode!(result)
    qs = %{
           "GoogleAccessId" => gcp_service_account,
           "Expires" => expires,
           "Signature" => signed_blob
         } |> URI.encode_query
    Enum.join(["#{@base_url}#{resource}", "?", qs])
  end

  def get_connection() do
    {:ok, token} = Goth.Token.for_scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform")
    GoogleApi.Storage.V1.Connection.new(token.token)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your use case:

1. Create two service accounts:

   ```
   gcloud iam service-accounts create signblob --description signblob
   gcloud iam service-accounts create signforme --description signforme
   # signblob will sign for signforme
   ```
2. Set the IAM role (`roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`) for the `signblob` service account:

   ```
   gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding myproject --member signblob@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
   ```
3. Create a VM as a service account using `signblob` service:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances create instance-10 --zone=us-central1-a --service-account=signblob@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com
   ```
4. SSH to the instances just created:

   ```
   gcloud compute ssh instance-10 --zone=us-central1-a
   ```
5. Create a file on the instance:

   ```
   nano file
   cat file
   # This is a file
   ```
6. Sign the file (blob) using `gcloud` tool for `signforme` service account using `--log-http` flag:

   ```
   gcloud iam service-accounts sign-blob --iam-account signblob-source@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com file output --log-http
   ```
7. Output:

   ```
    signed blob [file] as [output] for [signforme@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
   ```

This is the curl command that I run on the VM `instance-10` created before:

```
      curl --request POST 'https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/signblob-source%40myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com:signBlob?prettyPrint=true&key=[API KEY]' --header 'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS TOKEN]'  --header 'Accept: application/json'  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"payload":"VGhpcyBpcyBhIGZpbGUgCg=="}'   --compressed
```

Where ACCESS TOKEN is `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`

Output:

```
   {"keyId": ,"signedBlob":}
```